# struts, include jsp page

Tags: jsp, struts

I need to include jsp pages to a jsp page.

I had

`page="<%=contextPath%>/admin/admin_left.jsp"`

and i want to include than in a jsp page.
Please, help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use

```
<jsp:include page="/admin/admin_left.jsp" />
```